# Numbering of graphics is with a point before the number ('.1' instead of '1')

Tags: graphics, numbering, includegraphics

I have no idea why this is happening. As far as I can see the document I am working with only uses the '\usepackage{graphicx}'

When I inculde a graphic like this:

```
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figure1.png}
    \caption{Lösung des Beispiel Differentialgleichungssystems}
\end{figure} 
\FloatBarrier
```

It results in including the graphic with this text under it

> Abbildung .1: Lösung des Beispiel Differentialgleichungssystems

How can I change the numbering from '.1' to just '1'?

Comment: Two possibilities source of the period are `\figurename` and `\thefigure`.  The caption option `labelsep` comes after the number, not before.  The graphicx package has nothing to do with any of them.

Comment: you have not shown any code but most likely it is trying to print something like chapternumber.figurenumber in a setting where you have no chapters.

Comment: Including 
\usepackage{chngcntr}
 
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
solved the problem